# excel formula to Countif none sequential cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am trying to build a formula to calc the percentage of cells that are not "x" in a non-sequential range.

ie...

```
  =COUNTIF(H10,N10,T10,Z10,AF10,AL10,B14,H14,N14,T14,Z14,AF14,AL14,B19,H19,N19,T19,Z19,AL19,B23,H23,N23,T23,Z23,AL23,"x")
```

I also tried using a named range

```
=(COUNTIF(my_rng,"x")
```

but neither are working

if there is a better way using countifs to do this as well that would help

essentially I want to find the percentage of a,b,c so if there is a way to countif header cell is "a" and cell directly under that is x?

[image]

output would be

A: 3

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53541893/edit) to give us a sample of your data and the expected output?

Comment: sorry forgot the attachment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your sample is in Range `A1:L11` and the strings `a`, `b` and `c` and in `P2:P4`, insert the following in `Q2`:

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:L$10,P2,A$3:L$11,"x")
```

and populate down

edit: changed to Scott's more elegant solution

Comment: So much more elegant than mine -- I really should not assume this kind of thing won't work...